# How to show loading gif image while content called via javascript is loading?

Tags: jquery, loading

On my page I have javascript that loads new content in `<div id="content"></div>` from other page located at: `inc/content.php`. I would like to know how can I show animated gif image `loading.gif` in `<div id="content"></div>` while new content gets loaded into it? and once loaded hide gif and show new conntent?

Thank You )))
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewNext()
{
$("#content").load("inc/content.php");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="nextfLuky" onClick="viewNext();return false;">Next fLuky</button>

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**content in inc/content.php page:**

```
<div id="text">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function viewNext(){
    $('#content').html('<img src="loading.gif" />').load("inc/content.php");
}
```

When you use load() it will replace anything in the element, including the gif so you dont have to manually hide it.

Comment: It shows gif image for a while and than it goes away, but no content gets displayed.

Comment: omg, sory the color of text is white thats why I didn't see it )))

Answer (score 3):

```
function viewNext()
    {
    $('#content').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');
    $("#content").load("inc/content.php");
}
```

This will do it.

Comment: I'll try it now ))) Just in case, I assumed before that I would have to set display none and than on load set display to block for <div id="content"></div>  or is it unnecessary and am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#content').append('<img id="delete_me_spinner2" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0" style="text-decoration: none" alt="Loading" />');
    var y = $.post(.....)
                .complete(function(data) {
                $('#delete_me_spinner2').remove();
    //check ajax went ok
        });
```

Comment: $.load is a wrapper to ease things using $.get, $.get is similar to $.post, and both $.post and $.get are wrappers for $.ajax :) check http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details, i only wanted to specify that you add the image before requesting ,and then delete it after